# Which is faster, redis LPUSH or RPUSH?

Tags: redis

I'm flexible for my application architecture in that I can use a queue or a stack. Is there a performance benefit to using either [LPUSH](https://redis.io/commands/lpush) or [RPUSH](https://redis.io/commands/rpush)?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is one more `if` in the `RPUSH` flow, but it is neglectable. Both are the same.

Run a few times `redis-benchmark <params> lpush myllist __rand_int__` and a few times `redis-benchmark <params> rpush myrlist __rand_int__` and compare the `requests per second` you get in each run.